# Parsing the result from author_pendingExtrinsics

Tags: subxt

What return type should I use in subxt to be able to parse the result from `author_pendingExtrinsics`?

I have implemented a wrapper call and returning a vector of `OpaqueExtrinsic`:

```
async fn author_pending_extrinsics(&self) -> Result<Vec<OpaqueExtrinsic>, subxt::Error> {
   self.rpc.request("author_pendingExtrinsics", rpc_params![]).await;
}
```

This is okay, but I need to get the signer and the nonce from the results. It should be possible as polkadot-js there is a type called `Extrinsic` with all the information I need.

Running the call in the polkadot-js web ui returns:

```
3: author.pendingExtrinsics: Vec<Extrinsic>
[
  {
    isSigned: true
    method: {
      args: {
        dest: {
          Id: 4hNgHEdC6EZYHPFJrxFt19m3zBMbTb6ZErSbo9idCpX6n2zU
        }
        value: 9,500,000,000,000
      }
      method: transfer
      section: balances
    }
    era: {
      ImmortalEra: 0x00
    }
    nonce: 1
    signature: 0xbe779752c8893fc895cbca17b2b47b8fcde7627f1dd93d022354ba13d777f361befebc9f0862c5821c995ff1145d543114ea55fa89120d85b16815775f67658e
    signer: {
      Id: 4hNohKFDvDG8qf5SHPjhg3dhGFe4uRp136tm8eHNQ72xSYXB
    }
    tip: 0
  }
]
```

I have searched in the auto generated docs for my project(`cargo doc --open`) but could not find any suitable existing or auto generated type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Subxt doesn't expose the things you'd need to be able to decode these in a sensible way.

If you wanted to try it anyway, you could take the following steps:

1. Add the RPC method a definition like this to LegacyRpcMethods (or otherwise call it:

```rust
async fn author_pending_extrinsics(&self) -> Result<Vec<Bytes>, subxt::Error> {
   self.rpc.request("author_pendingExtrinsics", rpc_params![]).await;
}
```

(I'm sortof guessing but I think that's what you need)

2. Run something like this (not really tested):

```rust
use subxt::{OnlineClient, PolkadotConfig};
use subxt::{
    backend::rpc::RpcClient,
    backend::legacy::LegacyRpcMethods,
    blocks::Extrinsics,
    config::Config,
};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let rpc_client = RpcClient::from_url("ws://localhost:9944").await?;
    let rpc_methods = LegacyRpcMethods::<PolkadotConfig>::new(rpc_client.clone());
    let api = OnlineClient::<PolkadotConfig>::from_rpc_client(rpc_client).await?;

    // Get pending exts:
    let pending_exts = rpc_methods.author_pending_extrinsics().await?;

    // Make them the right shape:
    let pending_exts = pending_exts.into_iter().map(|e| e.0).collect();

    // Feed them into our Extrinsics struct (this new fn would need to be made pub)
    let exts = Extrinsics::new(
        api.clone(),
        pending_exts,
        // Some internal cache object:
        std::sync::Arc::new(futures::lock::Mutex::new(None)),
        // ExtrinsicPartTypeIds::new would need to be made pub too:
        ExtrinsicPartTypeIds::new(api.metadata().clone()),
        <PolkadotConfig as Config>::Hash::random(),
    );

    // from here you can do all of the usual stuff that Subxt can 
    // with extrinsics (iterate, decode them etc).

    Ok(())
}
```

You can see that a couple of things need making public and it's hideous (because this isn't a public API).

Please open an issue in the Subxt repo if you'd like this to be a public interface and we can discuss the use case and talk there :)

Comment: The real problem I was trying to solve was about getting the nonce compensated for pending extrinsics, and we fixed it in this https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/pull/1250 @jsdw if you have a look at my other PR we will have some examples how to use it as well there.

Comment: Ah ok great, I'm still catching up after some time off :)